# Replace Character in String with SQL Server Table Trigger on Insert\Update

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

**Answered

I am attempting to create a trigger that will replace a character `’` (MS Word Smart Quote) with a proper apostrophe `'` when new data is inserted or updated by a user from our website.

The special apostrophe may be found anywhere on a 5000 NVarchar column and may be found multiple times in the same string.

Any easy replace statement for this?

```
REPLACE(Column,'’','''')
```

Comment: I suggest that you make a scalar function that takes nvarchar(5000) as input, uses a loop to replace and returns a nvarchar(5000) value. Then use this function in your trigger.

Comment: @Adish why would you suggest creating a scalar function and a loop? That is the absolute slowest way to do this. The replace statement posted by the OP would be FAR better than a performance killing scalar function with another performance killing loop.

Comment: I would use your REPLACE that you posted. It will replace all instances of ’ with ' and is super fast.

Comment: @SeanLange Yes, you are right. My suggestion was not correct. I was thinking of a scenario where there are consecutive characters to be replaced by one instance of same/another character, like 4 spaces or 3 spaces to be replaced by 1 space. That is not the requirement here. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Even with multiple spaces you can do it without any kind of looping. :) If you need that technique you can read about it here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68378/

Comment: Yes I ended up just using the Replace, I was getting some .NET errors but that was because some of my other columns were not needed in select Statement of trigger.

Comment: @SeanLange Tx for the link. Nice method by Jeff Modem.

Comment: @James You can answer your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to argue that you should probably look at doing this in your applications instead of from within SQL Server. That's NOT the answer you're looking for - but it would probably make more sense.

Typically, when I see questions like this I instantly worry about devs trying to 'defeat' SQL Injection. If that's the case, this approach will NEVER work - as per:

http://sqlmag.com/database-security/sql-injection-beyond-basics

That said, if you're not focused on that and just need to get rid of 'pesky' characters, then REPLACE() will work (and likely be your best option), but I'd still argue that you're probably better off tackling 'formatting' issues like this from within your applications. Or in other words, treat SQL Server as your data repository - something that stores your raw data. Then, if you need to make it 'pretty' or 'tweak' it for various outputs/displays, then do that on the way out to your users by means of your application(s).